# Is my SATA cable damaged?

Tags: ssd, disk-utility, sata

Macbook Pro Mid 2012, original SSD.

TLDR; Why could I clone my unmountable drive from an external enclosure but not internally?

My SSD broke down a few days ago. It was detected, but I was unable to mount it, and I got I/O errors when trying to clone (restore in Disk Utility) the drive (no logs saved). After Disk Utility and DiskWarrior failed to resolve the issue I put the internal SSD into an external enclosure. From the enclosure I was suddenly able to clone the drive. My question is, what possible explanations for this are there? My guess is that the SATA connector is damaged, but I hope I'm wrong.

Update: A fresh install (made from the external enclosure) still has the same mounting issues when booted internally.

Update 2: After a few more hours of research I'm more or less convinced that the cable is toast. Apparently it's a common occurrence with certain Macbook models.

Comment: It could be the cable or any other part related to the HDD really. A cable might be the easiest thing to try and replace, of course

Comment: Another indicator of a dying SATA cable is that the sleeping LED on a MBP stops working. The LED is on the same ribbon as the SATA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the cable, and everything is now back to normal. So, as I suspected, the cable was the culprit.

Instructions on how to replace the SATA cable is easily found online

(search for things like `replace hard drive cable macbook`).

The only tricky part was to connect the sleep LED to the cable, but if you just check how the old cable is connected you'll be fine.